# How to correctly send post in web adres in browser

Tags: post, browser, send

Why when I use this code in web vulnerability scanner.. in HTTP editor.. works and showing me what I want..

```
POST /server.php HTTP/1.1
Host: wf.net.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.63 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*

id=2365&is_ajax=1&set=getMyData
```

but when I use this code in a browser, it doesn't show anything

```
server.php?id=2365&is_ajax=1&set=getMyData
```

Why :( ?

Comment: You can't POST data through the URL. The data must be sent separately in the request body

Answer (score 0):

That code that you put into your browser uses **HTTP GET**

What you are trying to do is **HTTP POST**

GET requests can be done through a URL, whereas POST cannot. With GET, your data is included in the address - whereas for POST, the data is included in the body of an HTTP request (separate from the address)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp